# Implementing TCP request and answer

Tags: java

1. I'm creating an application where **client connects** to server, retrieves some data and after that **connection is closed**.
2. He spends some time changing that data and then **connects again** to the server sends it back and **connection is closed**.
3. At server data is compared with original and saved to database if it validates.

I see only one solution to this - **creating two `ServerSocket` one for input and one for output**. But it does not seem good solution. Is this the way to do it or is there something else? **How can I determine purpose of connection?**

PS I'm using JAVA 8.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is off-topic here: we deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions (see our [FAQ]). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].